# 500 Internal Server Error: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, properties

I trying to register a user in a mongodb database with express, but when i do a POST call to

```
localhost:3000/users/register
```

with the body:

```
{
    "firstName": "Jason",
    "lastName": "Watmore",
    "username": "jason",
    "email": "jason@jason.com",
    "password": "my-super-secret-password"
}
```

Postman gives: 500 Internal Server Error with this body:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;username&#39; of undefined
    at Object.create (E:\Drive\Desarollo de Aplicaciones Web\Proyecto Final\apiREST\users\user.service.js:42:50)
    at register (E:\Drive\Desarollo de Aplicaciones Web\Proyecto Final\apiREST\users\users.controller.js:23:17)
```

This is the method to which the error points

```
async function create(userParam) {
    // validate

    if (await User.findOne({ username: userParam.username })) {
        throw 'Username "' + userParam.username + '" is already taken';
    }
```

What is happening and how can I fix it?

There is the controller to the point where it calls the method that fails:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userService = require('./user.service');

// routes
router.post('/authenticate', authenticate);
router.post('/register', register);
router.get('/', getAll);
router.get('/current', getCurrent);
router.get('/:id', getById);
router.put('/:id', update);
router.delete('/:id', _delete);

module.exports = router;

function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    userService.authenticate(req.body)
        .then(user => user ? res.json(user) : res.status(400).json({ message: 'Username or password is incorrect' }))
        .catch(err => next(err));
}

function register(req, res, next) {
    userService.create(req.body)
        .then(() => res.json({}))
        .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, your parameter is undefined.

Comment: Could you please add the complete controller code of post api to your question?

Comment: Added the controller code and the post call

Comment: looks like `req.body` is `undefined`. have you mounted `body-parser`

Comment: Yeah i have this in app.js:
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'false'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Answer (score 0):

Hope You have added body parser::
 Express comes with body parser
 Apply these middlewares before you initialize your route.

```
const app = require("express")();
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(json());
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you `userParam` is undefined. So, it's clear that   `req.body` cannot be parsed correctly.

Since you mentioned you already have the body-parser middleware in the express app, you should also make sure that the `app.use(bodyParse())` is placed before the you did the routing.